# -webkit-tap-highlight-color in Android 3 browser

Tags: android, webkit

We have a form with a number of inputs.
Whenever I tap the form, it's highlighted gray.

I have

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); }
```

(I used rgba(255,255,255,0) as well)

This disables this highlight behavior on iOS5 and Android 4. Android 2.3.4 doesn't highlight as well (I suppose it just doesn't have this behavior).

But on Galaxy Tab 10.1 the gray box is still there - any way to fix it?

Comment: I think this is a Samsung customization issue.

Comment: To validate this you can try it in the SDK. I have seen quite a few problems with the Samsung SII and SIII that are not present on the Nexus, and not on the SDK either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Strangely, this works! While applying this CSS rule directly to canvas, doesn't. And this issue seems to be specific to Samsung.