# -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); doesn't work on newer android versions?

Tags: android, cordova, highlighting

i have a phonegap android app and want to disable the highlighting when "clicking" on something. i found this to prevent the highlighting:

```
*{
/* Prevent any object from being highlighted upon touch event*/
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

it doesn't work for me. i also found somebody that says that isnt working anymore in newer android versions (>4.1). So is there a solution to prevent this highlighting in newer versions?

Comment: What happens if you follow that with `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;`?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452702/webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-android-3-browser

Comment: "transparent" also doesn't work for me on a Samsung S3 Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular Material, here is a solution:
Problem was in older version of Angular Material. With version 0.10 there is no problem with that.
If you're using Visual Studio and you installed Angular Material with Nuget, your version will be 0.8.3, so you need to upgrade version of Angular Material.